# MVC- Retrieve the original value of an EditorFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

On the edit page of my website I want users to be able to edit qty's and then have it change the model. This is why I am using 'editorFor'. The problem is that I still want to return the value of the model before it was edited to the controller post method.

For example, if a user edited a qty from 7 to 10, I would want the model to change to 10 but I would also want the view to return 7 to the controller. How can I do this?

Here is my editorFor code

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item_qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item_qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my edit post method

```
[RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.ModifyWorkOrder)]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Audit]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,JobOrderID,StartDate,CompleteDate,jobSection,ItemID,item_qty,actual_item_qty,ComponentID,comp_qty,actual_comp_qty,PartID,part_qty,actual_part_qty,Notes,subDetail")] JODetails jODetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                JobOrder jo = db.JobOrders.Find(jODetails.JobOrderID);

                    db.Entry(jODetails).State = EntityState.Modified;


                    JODetails currentData = db.JODetails.Find(jODetails.ID);
                    Component comp = db.Components.Find(jODetails.ComponentID);
                    Item i = db.Items.Find(jODetails.ItemID);

                    int newItemCount = jODetails.item_qty != null ? (int)jODetails.item_qty : 0;                 
                    int oldItemCount = 0;
                    int itemDiff = newItemCount - oldItemCount;

           }
```

Comment: Very unclear what exactly you have a problem with... Are you trying to return both new and original value from browser to controller? "the view  to return X to the controller" is confusing because view does not *return* anything to controller as view takes *input* from a controller and not other way around...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry yes I'm new to mvc so still figuring things out. But currently how it stands is that once the editorFor value is changed, the last value (value it was changed from) is no longer retrieveable. It is important that I can somehow return both values to my edit Post method but not sure the best way to do this

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have edited my question to hopefully provide you with better understanding. But basically I want the oldItemCount to equal the value of what the model was before it was edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well enough, you don't need to return the value from the view. When the `model` is passed to the controller the value in the database has not been changed, you can read it again. Something like this:

```cs
// First. Grab the previous quantity...
// This approach won't work because of EF is already TRACKING the entity
// JODetails currentData = db.JODetails.Find(jODetails.ID);
// So, you have to access data like this...
var currentData = db.JODetails.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(j => j.ID == jODetails.ID);

int previousQuantity = currentData?.item_qty;

//... do whatever with previousQuantity prop & new JODetails model. Don't forget to check if currentData is null 

// Just NOW. Mutate the object via EF...
db.Entry(jODetails).State = EntityState.Modified;

// THEN. Commit changes...
db.SaveChanges();
```

It's not until you `SaveChanges()` that the record in the database it's really changed. Read some docs about how EF tracks, modifies & save objects.

This could be very helpful to understand this...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Of course if you **NEED** to retrieve the Quantity data from the view (can't see why) there are some alternatives such as a `ViewModel` but I think this would do the trick. Yes, with this approach there's one more trip to the database, but it's minimal.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, one issue though. When I moved it there I received entity error that says 'Attaching an entity of type 'PIC_Program_1._0.Models.JODetails' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value'  this is strange because the only lines I moved above it were the currentdata and olditemvalue like in your answer

Comment: You're welcome @JoshFontaine. Again, this is an EF way to work with entities. The `find` method by default **tracks** the entity, so it is in use, as the error correctly explains. Now, I've added two things: The `AsNoTracking()` method (pretty self explanatory) and changed to `FirstOrDefault()` method to get the ENTITY value.